# How to show that calculation is going in MATLAB App

Tags: matlab, matlab-app-designer

A rough app I have recreated.When the user clicks "Calculate", I want to show that calculations are happening like a progress bar or "Calculate" Button changes to "Calculating" and after calculations are done revert back to "Calculate".
Code for app is:

```
a = app.Number1EditField.Value;
b = app.Number2EditField.Value;
x = 10*rand(1,1);
eqn = 12- (a+b+x);
while eqn ~= 0
        x = x + 0.0001;
end
app.AnswerEditField.Value = x;
```

P.S I know here the answer won't come.

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: What does "I know here the answer won't come" mean? Anyway, please read here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I meant according to the equation in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`uiprogressdlg`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uiprogressdlg.html) to create a (modal) progress bar.

Answer (score 3):

If you create a gui with the appdesigner, and have a pushbutton with handle `calculateButton`, you can use the following as its callback:

```
% Button pushed function: calculateButton
function calculateButtonPushed(app, event)
    set(app.UIFigure,'Pointer','watch'); drawnow;
    app.calculateButton.Text = 'Calculating...';

    pause(2); % calculate whatever, pause for demo

    set(app.UIFigure,'Pointer','arrow'); drawnow;
    app.calculateButton.Text = 'Calculate';
end
```

This will both change the text, and change the pointer to a wait cursor.